# How to minimize the sum of squared differences between the input of two functions changing only few parameters in one of the two function

Tags: r, solver, minimization

I'm trying to minimize the sum of squared differences of the prices of two different option models.

I have two function.

```
Function 1 <- function(phi,SpotPrice,Strike, TimetoMaturity, Volat, Liborrate, DividendYield)
```

and

```
Function 2 <- function(Strike, Liborrate, theta, alpha1, alpha2, beta1, beta2, TimetoMaturity)
```

and would like to minimize the sum of squared differences of the prices arising from this two function modifying only the parameters theta, alpha1, alpha2, beta1, beta2

Answer (score 0):

As function one does not contain any of your arguments the result will be a constant for this question so you can calculate this.
here is a small example of how you could minimize two arguments (a & c):

```r
result_function_1<-45
function_two<-function(a,b,c,d){
  sum(matrix((1:40/11)%%3, ncol=4) %*% c(a,b,c,d))
}
diffFun<-function(x,...,result_function_1)
{
  (function_two(a=x[1], c=x[2],...)-result_function_1)^2
}
optim(1:2, diffFun, b=4,d=5,result_function_1=result_function_1)
#> $par
#> [1]  2.234503 -2.756504
#> 
#> $value
#> [1] 9.546059e-07
#> 
#> $counts
#> function gradient 
#>       47       NA 
#> 
#> $convergence
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> $message
#> NULL
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

On this basis you should be able to extent this to 5 arguments. Although minimizing in 5 dimensions might be computationally more challenging.